# What flying insect is this? Resembles Wasp / Crane Fly / Moth?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What insect is this?

Found this in southern `Bangalore, India`. Looked dangerous, flew really slowly with its body upright and legs spread out and landed on a wall.

Size: about `1.5 inches` tall, `1.5 inches` wide, when spread.

These photos are zoomed in and rather dull colored, but the actual color was a bright orange, like `#FF9050` and dark black.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: The long legs suggest one of the crane fly families (Tipulidae, Cylindrotomidae, Pediciidae, Limoniidae, Tanyderidae most likely; Ptychopteridae and Trichoceridae less so); the pointed abdomen tells me your subject was female.  The patterned wings might make identification a little easeir--if India has a version of bugguide.net, that would be your next stop.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost: Thanks, you pointed me the right way. I dug it up. See my posted answer! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Pselliophora laeta**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pselliophora#/media/File:Pselliophora_laeta-Kadavoor-2016-06-26-002.jpg), a species of crane fly (***Tipulidae***) in the ***Ctenophorinae*** subfamily.

Route to discovery: Reverse image searching my own photo on Google led me to a matching image on [Naturalista (Familia Tipulidae)](https://www.naturalista.mx/taxa/51225-Tipulidae), and in-turn to [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/photos/370899), which showed me to [Genus Dictenidia](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/299363). Further [Googling for "Genus Dictenidia"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dictenidia) brought up many families of crane-fly, which I visually scanned until I spotted it -- [Pselliophora](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pselliophora&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLSz9U3sExPLywsU4KyC8wykrXk_IvSE_Myi3OdcxKLizPTMpMTSzLz84IzU1LLEyuLAbYHNzM6AAAA&npsic=-512&ved=0ahUKEwi3ku3rs4DcAhVFrI8KHfEfB5gQ-BYIPA)! That led to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pselliophora), and to [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pselliophora#/media/File:Pselliophora_laeta-Kadavoor-2016-06-26-002.jpg), which mentions its source to be [whatsthatbug](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2010/09/30/mating-crane-flies-from-india/), where the discussion cites **Pselliophora laeta** on [India Nature Watch](https://www.indianaturewatch.net/displayimage.php?id=65314).

--

[image: 1]
Source: https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/299363
Observed: Thiruvananthapuram, India; Jul 28, 2012 5:13 PM IST

**Mating Crane Flies from India**
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
Source: https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2010/09/30/mating-crane-flies-from-india/
Observed: Mumbai, India; Sep 30, 2010 1:43 AM IST